# I get a dereference of a possibly null reference in a method returning Task? And calling a method returning Task?

Tags: c#, .net

The following code throws an error

> Dereference of possibly null reference

at the line with the comment:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public class LowLevelClass
{ 
    public async Task? SomeMethod()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello"));
    }
}

public class TopLevelClass
{
    private LowLevelClass? lowLevelClass = null;

    public TopLevelClass()
    { 
        lowLevelClass = new LowLevelClass();
    }

    public async Task? SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        if(lowLevelClass != null)
            await lowLevelClass.SomeMethod(); // Dereference of possibly null reference
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TopLevelClass topLevelClass = new TopLevelClass();
        Task t = Task.Run(async () => await topLevelClass.SomeOtherMethod());
        t.Wait();
    }
}
```

I think this is due the the possibility that `LowLevelClass.SomeMethod` could return a null `Task`.

How can I avoid the warning?

I tried to insert conditions of the not null for `lowLevelClass` object or to modify the code as

```
await lowLevelClass?.SomeMethod();
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Why are you declaring a bunch of references as nullable when cannot be null?

Comment: _"How can I avoid the warning?"_ : `public async Task? SomeMethod()` => `public async Task SomeMethod()`

Comment: Oh, and: `t.Wait();` => `await t;` which needs `public static void Main()` => `public static async Task Main()`

Comment: There are very few reasons indeed why you'd ever use `Task?`, as having to deal with `null` would complicate handling considerably. Where you need a "do nothing" `Task`, you can just use `Task.CompletedTask`.

Comment: Thank you to verybody... Yes I can declare the method to return a `Task` and not a `Task?`. But in the former case how can I check if the returning `Task` is not `null`?

Comment: You don't have to check this for null (you even can't if you use await). Your awaitable method usually returns something or is void. The moment you define the method as async, the return value is wrapped into a Task<T> or in case of a void method (no return value) a simple Task is returned. This said, the *result*  value returned by `await` (or Task.Result) can be null. The awaited Task object itself won't be null. What you see is just a compiler warning because you declared the return type as nullable. It's not an error and it does not mean that the warning will or can fulfill.

Comment: Because a method that is of Type `async Task` does not return anything it's impossible that it returns `null`. The compiler should report an error and refuse to compile if such a method returns a value. As soon as you declare a method as `async` async/await  will create the Task object implicitly. If you don't declare the method as `async` and the method is not implemented properly, the return value could be null indeed. This is because without the `async` the method is responsible to wrap the result into a Task object (i.e. return a Task or Task<T>).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want your `lowlevel.SomeMethod()` and your top level `SomeOtherMethod()` to unambiguously return a `Task`. There's never a good reason to return a `Task?`, and especially not in an `async Task` signature. If there is nothing to do, the methods can return `Task.CompletedTask`

The getting or not of warnings may depend on whether your code is using a recent version of C# and have nullable reference types enabled, which it looks like you have. If you do, you will get more “possible null” warnings. But warnings or not, I'd never use `async Task?`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you declared that `SomeMethod()` may return null. So this would be perfectly legal :

```
public Task? SomeMethod() => null;
```

So when we run `await lowLevelClass.SomeMethod();` we might `await null`, and that is not legal. Just changing the signature to `public async Task SomeMethod()` should fix it.

The compiler does not try to guess if something can actually be null, at least not outside a single compilation unit. If you declare that the return value can be null, so you need to handle null values.